# How to trigger the cube portfolio by custom jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to trigger the Cube portfolio filter by custom JQuery. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mieJ.png)
**For example:**

I have an slider in cube portfolio, with more than 20 projects with various technology. If I slide the div, the filter should active on particular technology like "Animation" the filter of "Animation" text should active.

Is there any solution or any other alternate slider for this?

Comment: share something like working code fiddle...It will be easy for us to resolve...

Comment: See at Slider Projects: http://scriptpie.com/cubeportfolio/live-preview/templates/slider-testimonials/

Answer (score 0):

First, your requirement is unclear. It would be helpful if you could be more specific.

**My understanding:** You need to trigger an action [Filter] when the slider is changed.

I am giving a basic layout on How to trigger an event based on a particular event. You can improvise from this.

**Step 1:**
Initiate a call while clicking next/previous button for sliders movements. [Let's say you are calling the method **TriggerSlide()** ]

**Step 2:**
Inisde TriggerSlide() Call a function that will give you the current slider [Let's say you are calling **GetCurrentSlider()**]. Store it's id/value in a variable.

**Step 3:**
Now call the **Filter()** function and pass the current slider's id as a parameter. Now your filter function should take care of its work.

***Base methods:***

```
 //Triggering a method on clicking the prev/next arrows
        $('.cbp-nav-prev,.cbp-nav-next').click(function(){ 

        });

//A method that will give you the current slider's Id/Value.
       function GetCurrentSlider(){
         //your code here
       }

//Filter method that you intend to call when the slider is changed.
       function FilterTech(slider){
          //your code here
       }
```

**Final piece:**

```
$('.cbp-nav-prev,.cbp-nav-next').click(function(){     
      var currrentSlider = GetCurrentSlider();
      FilterTech(currrentSlider);
});
```

> *Note:* I have tested this code on the site you mentioned by calling alert functions and the triggers work perfectly fine. I remind you
>   that this is just a layout and you can do your thing to make it work
>   on sliding/ any actions you'd like to accomplish.